# Table Name from Model

Tags: django

When I have created query for the following model

```
class City(models.Model):
    city_id         = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

the table name comes like "lookups_city" where "lookups" is my module name. Is there any way to just consider only the class name? Because I'm migrating my application from another platform to Python where I have table as "city".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define `db_table` in your model meta class

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table

```
class Meta:
   db_table = 'city'
```

Answer (score 2):

You would want

```
class City(models.Model):
    city_id         = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
class Meta:
    db_table = 'city'
```

the `db_table` option allows you to use a custom name for your table rather than the default appname_model format